# Multiple ItemsControl on single collection applies filter to all views at once

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

Prerequisites: .NET 4.5.1

I have three `TreeView` controls that display three filtered variants of single collection instance. When I try to apply a filter on `Items` collection of one of controls this filter propagates to other controls automatically which prevents me to use different filters on different controls.

Is there any way to achieve the same result without having to maintain three instances of collections at once?

An example that shows the problem follows below. First two ListViews are bound to the same collection instance directly. Third one is bound to that instance through `CompositeCollection`. And the fourth is bound to independent collection. When I press "Set Filter" button `ItemsControl.Items.Filter` property if first `ListView` is set to `IsAllowedItem` method of WTest window. After this second `istView.Items.Filter` property somehow points to the same method while third and fourth ListView returns null. Another effect is that though third `ListView` shows null filter its collection is still filtered as you can see if you run the example. This very strange effect arises from the behavior of ItemCollection class that when based on `ItemsSource` property of owner element acquires underlying `CollectionView` from some application-wide storage via `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultCollectionView` method. I don't know the reason of this implementation but suspect suspect that it's performance.

Test window WTest.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Local.WTest"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:c="clr-namespace:System.Collections;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Local"
        Name="_WTest" Title="WTest" Height="300" Width="600">
    <Window.Resources>
        <c:ArrayList x:Key="MyArray">
            <s:String>Letter A</s:String>
            <s:String>Letter B</s:String>
            <s:String>Letter C</s:String>
        </c:ArrayList>
        <CompositeCollection x:Key="MyCollection" >
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MyArray}"/>
        </CompositeCollection>
        <c:ArrayList x:Key="AnotherArray">
            <s:String>Letter A</s:String>
            <s:String>Letter B</s:String>
            <s:String>Letter C</s:String>
        </c:ArrayList>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Name="FilterLabel1"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Name="FilterLabel2"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Name="FilterLabel3"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Name="FilterLabel4"/>
        <ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Name="View1" ItemsSource="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MyArray}"/>
        <ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Name="View2" ItemsSource="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MyArray}"/>
        <ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Name="View3" ItemsSource="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MyCollection}"/>
        <ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Name="View4" ItemsSource="{StaticResource ResourceKey=AnotherArray}"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Content="Set Filter" Click="OnSetFilterButtonClick"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind WTest.xaml.cs

```
namespace Local
{
    using System.Windows;

    public partial class WTest : Window
    {
        public WTest()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            UpdateFilterLabels();
        }

        private bool IsAllowedItem(object item)
        {
            return "Letter A" == (string)item;
        }

        private void OnSetFilterButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            View1.Items.Filter = IsAllowedItem;
            UpdateFilterLabels();
        }

        private void UpdateFilterLabels()
        {
            FilterLabel1.Text = (null == View1.Items.Filter) ? "No Filter" : View1.Items.Filter.Method.Name;
            FilterLabel2.Text = (null == View2.Items.Filter) ? "No Filter" : View2.Items.Filter.Method.Name;
            FilterLabel3.Text = (null == View3.Items.Filter) ? "No Filter" : View3.Items.Filter.Method.Name;
            FilterLabel4.Text = (null == View4.Items.Filter) ? "No Filter" : View4.Items.Filter.Method.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

And result after "Set Filter" button is clicked:
[Example: result of clicking "Set Filter" button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPdFQ.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create `CollectionViewSource` as a `Resource`.

   ```
   <CollectionViewSource x:Key="CVSKey" Source="{DynamicResource MyArray}"/>
   ```
2. Use this `CollectionViewSource` as your `ItemsSource` . Replace your View1 as :

   ```
   <!--<ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Name="View1" ItemsSource="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MyArray}"/>-->
   <ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Name="View1" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=CVSKey}}"/>
   ```

Thats it, now everything will work as you want it to.

Additionally, now you can apply filtering to this `CollectionViewSource` instead of View1 :

```
((CollectionViewSource)this.Resources["CVSKey"]).Filter += List_Filter;

void List_Filter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
{
    e.Accepted = (e.Item.ToString() == "Letter A") ? true : false;
}
```

Create separate `CollectionViewSource` for separate `ListBoxes` to create separate views from same underlying collection.

Search google for `CollectionViewSource`.

Comment: very good answer. reader can see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.collectionview?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) for more info. The key point is that in WPF applications, all collections have an associated default collection view.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `OnSetFilterButtonClick` Method as below

```
private void OnSetFilterButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
    //Create a new listview by the ItemsSource,Apply Filter to the new listview
    ListCollectionView listView = new ListCollectionView(View1.ItemsSource as IList); 
    listView.Filter = IsAllowedItem;
    View1.ItemsSource = listView;
    UpdateFilterLabels();
}
```

Comment: one collection can create more collectionviews, one listbox binding one collectionview.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution that does not require creating a `CollectionViewSource` resource in XAML or a `ListCollectionView` in code for every collection that needs its own filter.

My solution is to use an ValueConverter that converts the `ItemsSource` source to a `CollectionViewSource.View`

**ItemsSourceConverter:**

```cs
[ValueConversion(typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(IEnumerable))]
public class ItemsSourceConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is IEnumerable itemsSource && itemsSource != null)
        {
            return new CollectionViewSource() { Source = itemsSource }.View;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception($"Value must be an {nameof(IEnumerable)}");
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```xml
<Window ...>
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:ItemsSourceConverter x:Key="ItemsSourceConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
...
    <ItemsControl Name="View1", 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Collection1, Converter={StaticResource ItemsSourceConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" />
    <ItemsControl Name="View2", 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Collection3, Converter={StaticResource ItemsSourceConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" />
    <ItemsControl Name="View3", 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Collection3, Converter={StaticResource ItemsSourceConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" />
</Window>
```

**Code behind:**

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ObservableCollection<DataClass> Collection1 { get; private set; }
    ObservableCollection<DataClass> Collection2 { get; private set; }
    ObservableCollection<DataClass> Collection3 { get; private set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    ...

    private void SetFilters()
    {
        View1.Filter = (item) =>
        {
            // Filter logic
        };

        View2.Filter = (item) =>
        {
            // Filter logic
        };

        View2.Filter = (item) =>
        {
            // Filter logic
        };
    }

    ...
}
```

---

#### MVVM ItemsControl with Filter binding

If we want to use the above solution with MVVM, we can create an attached property to bind the `ItemsControl.Filter` to a filter defined in the ViewModel.

**Filter attached property:**

```cs
public static class CollectionViewExtensions
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FilterProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "Filter",
        typeof(Predicate<object>),
        typeof(CollectionViewExtensions),
        new PropertyMetadata(default(Predicate<object>), OnFilterChanged));

    public static void SetFilter(ItemsControl element, Predicate<object> value)
    {
        element.SetValue(FilterProperty, value);
    }

    public static Predicate<object> GetFilter(ItemsControl element)
    {
        return (Predicate<object>)element.GetValue(FilterProperty);
    }

    private static void OnFilterChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (d is ItemsControl itemsControl && itemsControl.Items.CanFilter)
        {
            if (e.OldValue is Predicate<object> oldPredicate)
            {
                itemsControl.Items.Filter -= oldPredicate;
            }

            if (e.NewValue is Predicate<object> newPredicate)
            {
                itemsControl.Items.Filter += newPredicate;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39438710/10927863

**XAML:**

```xml
<Window ...>
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:ItemsSourceConverter x:Key="ItemsSourceConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
...
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Collection1, Converter={StaticResource ItemsSourceConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" 
                  local:CollectionViewExtensions.Filter="{Binding Filter1}"/>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Collection3, Converter={StaticResource ItemsSourceConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" 
                  local:CollectionViewExtensions.Filter="{Binding Filter2}"/>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Collection3, Converter={StaticResource ItemsSourceConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" 
                  local:CollectionViewExtensions.Filter="{Binding Filter3}"/>
</Window>
```

**ViewModel:**

```cs
public class ViewModel
{
    ObservableCollection<DataClass> Collection1 { get; private set; }
    ObservableCollection<DataClass> Collection2 { get; private set; }
    ObservableCollection<DataClass> Collection3 { get; private set; }

    public Predicate<object> Filter1 { get; private set; }
    public Predicate<object> Filter2 { get; private set; }
    public Predicate<object> Filter3 { get; private set; }

    ...

    private void SetFilters()
    {
        Filter1 = (item) =>
        {
            // Filter logic
        };

        Filter2 = (item) =>
        {
            // Filter logic
        };

        Filter3 = (item) =>
        {
            // Filter logic
        };
    }

    ...
}
```