# How to filter combobox items based on the input text?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I would like to display a combo box whose items are supplied by the view model.
The combo box should be editable.
Based on the text currently input by the user, the combo box items should be filtered.

I am trying to apply the following solution pointed out in various resources on the topic (such as [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34382459/simple-wpf-combobox-filter), [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001842/dynamic-filter-of-wpf-combobox-based-on-text-input), [that article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-filter-data-in-a-view?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8), [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14497506/collectionviewsource-how-to-filter-data), [that blogpost](http://www.abhisheksur.com/2010/08/woring-with-icollectionviewsource-in.html), [that tutorial](https://www.wpftutorial.net/DataViews.html), etc.):

- My view model provides a collection view around the items.
- I have two-way bound the `Text` property of the combo box to a `CustomText` property in my view model.
- The `Filter` predicate on the collection view is set to check items based on whether their display name contains the `CustomText`.
- When `CustomText` is changed, the `Refresh` method on the items collection view is invoked.

I'd expect this to update the list of items in the combo box dropdown list whenever I modify the text. Unfortunately, the list remains the same.

If I place a breakpoint in my `Filter` predicate, it gets hit, but somehow, not always for each item.

---

**Here is a minimal example:**

Xaml for the window:

```
<Window x:Class="ComboBoxFilterTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ComboBoxFilterTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
            DisplayMemberPath="Name"
            IsEditable="True"
            Text="{Binding CustomText}"
            IsTextSearchEnabled="False"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The code-behind for the window:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace ComboBoxFilterTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = new MainViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

And the view model (here with the `Item` data class, which would normally reside elsewhere):

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace ComboBoxFilterTest
{
    public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private sealed class Item
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }

            public string Name { get; set; }
        }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            Items = new CollectionView(items)
            {
                Filter = item =>
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(customText))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }

                    if (item is Item typedItem)
                    {
                        return typedItem.Name.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(customText.ToLowerInvariant());
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            };
        }

        private readonly ObservableCollection<Item> items = new ObservableCollection<Item>
        {
            new Item{ Id = 1, Name = "ABC" },
            new Item{ Id = 2, Name = "ABCD" },
            new Item{ Id = 3, Name = "XYZ" }
        };

        public ICollectionView Items { get; }

        private string customText = "";

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public string CustomText
        {
            get => customText;
            set
            {
                if (customText != value)
                {
                    customText = value;
                    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(CustomText)));

                    Items.Refresh();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Basically, I think I'm doing the same as what is described [in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34382459/simple-wpf-combobox-filter), but apparently, something is still different as it doesn't work in my case.

Note that one slight difference is that I am not using `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView`, as I want to have several differently filtered views on the same collection rather than obtaining *the* default view.

---

Note that as a **workaround**, I could of course just return the appropriately filtered enumerable of items myself and fire a property changed event for such an enumerable property each time the filter changes. However, I understand relying on collection views is the proper WPF way, so I would prefer to do it "correctly".

Comment: I recommend to read this very short but informative docs to learn more: [Microsoft Docs: `CollectionView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.collectionview?view=net-5.0#remarks).

Comment: `CollectionViewSource` internally checks the type of the collection and creates the appropriate `ICollectionView` implementation. You should avoid to do this manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended pattern to avoid any problems like the one you are experiencing is to use `CollectionViewSource` as binding source.

As also mentioned in the docs, you should never create instances of `CollectionView` manually. You have to use a specialized sub-type according to the actual type of the source collection:

> "You should not create objects of this class [`CollectionView`] in your code. To create a collection view for a collection that only implements IEnumerable, create a CollectionViewSource object, add your collection to the Source property, and get the collection view from the View property." [Microsoft Docs: CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.collectionview?view=net-5.0#remarks)

`CollectionViewSource` internally does the type checking for you and creates a properly initialized `ICollectionView` implementation, that is appropriate for the actual source collection. `CollectionViewSource`, whether created in XAML or C#, is the recommended way to obtain an instance of `ICollectionView`, if the default view is not sufficient:

```
public ICollectionView Items { get; }
public CollectionViewSource ItemsViewSource { get; }

public ctor()
{      
  ObservableCollection<object> items = CreateObservableItems();
  this.ItemsViewSource = new CollectionViewSource() {Source = items};
  this.Items = this.ItemsViewSource.View;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work. I suppose why `CollectionView` is not abstract and has a public constructor is anyone's guess then.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a solution: As was suggested in [an answer on a related topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56888927/5206621), I used `ListCollectionView` instead of `CollectionView`.

For some reason, it works with `ListCollectionView` while it doesn't with `CollectionView`, even though the latter does not give any indication that it shouldn't (e.g. `CollectionView.CanFilter` returns `true`).

*I am going to accept this answer of my own for now, though if someone can provide an answer that actually provides an explanation for this behaviour, I'll be glad to accept such an answer instead.*